# How can I straighten a violin tailpiece (and do I need to)?

Tags: maintenance, violin

My violin tailpiece is at a noticeable angle, as shown in the pictures below. I assume this is partly because the bridge is quite steeply-raked (which presumably can't be altered significantly, as the bridge matches the profile of the fingerboard).

Is this something that would usually be seen as a problem? Is there any simple remedy that I could try myself, such as changing or removing the adjusters?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle the tailpiece takes depends on several factors- the shape of the bridge as you mentioned, the various tensions of the strings, the height and number of fine tuners, etc.  The only way to change the angle without changing the bridge or the strings is with the fine tuners: most violins are designed for having just one, so the tailpiece rides lower than planned if you have all four.

But actually, unless the tailpiece or a fine tuner is touching the belly of the violin, it's not a problem.  Check out your clearance: it should be at least a couple of millimeters or you're likely to put dings in the belly and of course not sound optimal.  As you suggest, the easiest thing would be to take off all the fine tuners except perhaps the E.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem since the tail piece is in equilibrium.  However, check your fine tuners regularly.  If they are close to the violin top, turn them out most of the way, coarse tune using the pegs, then adjust the fine tuners.